# Java add space between component and frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I use a gridLayout(1,2) and I put a JLabel and JTextField on it. the result at the right end looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to add more space between the border of the jframe and the jtextfield? So the jtextfield is not so close to the frame...

Answer (score 3):

Put an empty border around it:

```
    textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    textField.getBorder(), 
    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
```

Comment: i think @ControlAltDel has a better solution :)

Comment: 1+, Actually using the Border is a better idea, although the Border should be on the panel containing the components, not the text field itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Use Insets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html)

```
JTextField jf = new JTextField() {
  public Insets getInsets() {
    return new Insets (5,5,5,50);
  }
}
```

Comment: This puts the space in the text field. It does not add space between the component and the frame.